# How to diable the SOAP services on runtime in Websphere

Tags: soap, service, websphere

I have multiple SOAP services exposed to front end system. Similar way I have few other SOAP services which call to the another system.
Now I have a requirement to which I want to disable the SOAP service temporarily with out stopping the server(without any restart). I need to re-enable the service again after a particular time period with out restart.
How can I achieve this. Websphere is the application on which my services are deployed.

Comment: Traditional WebSphere or Liberty?  Jaxws or jax-rpc?  You could stop the application without a restart, if that's not too coarse.

Comment: Websphere and jaxws